# Remove inherited styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

Let me give a little preface. So the site I'm working on, is about half responsive half not. Right now I'm trying to make a responsive login that will work for non-responsive pages. When I test it it's all good BUT for whatever reason, there is a style sheet that targets **divs/p/** almost everything and over rides my styles *(note: the css that is over riding  is not class related but instead targets document sections **(div/p/span/etc)**)*. My question is, how can I prevent those styles from being applied to the document sections? To be more specific I don't want those section styles to be applied anywhere within the *login-container* div.

```
<div id="login-container" class="container content">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 login-header">
        Log In
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container login-form">
    <div id="loginform" runat="server">
        <p style="color: Red;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"/>
        </p>
        <fieldset id="formLogin" runat="server">

            <div class="col-xs-12 login-row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 login-label">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblUsername" AssociatedControlID="txtUsername" EnableViewState="False">Username</asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 login-row">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" CssClass="login-textbox" Height="36" placeholder="   &#xf007;" runat="server"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 login-label">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPassword" AssociatedControlID="txtPassword" EnableViewState="False">Password</asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 login-row">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" TextMode="Password" CssClass="login-textbox" Height="36" placeholder="   &#xf084;" runat="server"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="col-xs-12 login-row">
            <asp:Button ID="btnGo" runat="server" Text="Login" CssClass="btn btn-blue"/>
        </div>
        <%--Value of Request.QueryString["ContestantNumber"] (but really "item"): <%= QueryTest %>--%>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I inspect in the browser this happens [over riding css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bDHA.png)

Any suggestions? Is there some way to use jquery to only keep class defined styles?

Comment: Learn about style specificity.  That's your entire issue: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/  You need `#legacy-wrapper .login-header {... your styles here ... }`

Comment: Thanks! Although it was a little tedious I think your suggestion was the best solution.

Comment: My pleasure to help.  Things like this help you become a better coder over time - after having to do things like this, you learn to write less specific CSS if at all possible.  Tools like SCSS and LESS also make this less tedious (but end up creating equally large css)

Answer (score 0):

Either you use the third party CSS or you don't. If you want to blacklist CSS classes under specific classes you can do so by either

```
.yourClass .aClass, .yourClass .anotherClass {}
```

or you modify the overriden classes to work however you want it to. Both seem pretty redundant to me.

If the overrides are necessary, then I don't see why you just don't create your own structure inside the login scope. Borrow the features you like and implement the rest yourself but if you deviate too much then it's probably time to reconsider the general styling of the page in general.

Comment: Went ahead and combined your and cale b's suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

there is something known to be as reset CSS which resets all the inherited styles and after that, you can apply your own custom styles.
also, normalize do some thing similar it's on your requirement

here is the URL
reset CSS
https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

normalize CSS
https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/